# MariaDB INSERT value as COLUMN_CREATE (dynamic column)

Tags: mariadb, dynamic-columns, select-insert

I need insert dynamic column as select from another table.

I tried:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, photos)
VALUES
(12345,COLUMN_CREATE(SELECT file FROM photo WHERE ad_id = 12345));
```

and

```
INSERT INTO table (id, photos)
VALUES
(12345,SELECT COLUMN_CREATE(file) FROM photo WHERE ad_id = 12345));
```

and

```
INSERT INTO table (id, photos)
SELECT ad_id, COLUMN_CREATE(file) FROM photo WHERE ad_id = 12345;
```

And MariaDB always returns ***#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `table` (id, photos)
VALUES
(12345,COLUMN_CREATE(1, (SELECT file FROM photo WHERE ad_id = 12345)));
```

Put quotes around `table` as it is a reserved word ([List of MariaDB's reserved words](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/sql-language-structure/reserved-words/)).

Add the dynamic column's number or name to the COLUMN_CREATE function's arguments ([COLUMN_CREATE syntax](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/nosql/dynamic-columns/#column_create)), my example SQL uses 1 as column number.

Put the SELECT statement in parentheses as subqueries must be parenthesized.

Comment: Thanks! But now MariaDB return **#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row**

I need insert more values (rows) into dynamic column and I thought MariaDB automatically process it.

Comment: @Ondřej: Neither COLUMN_CREATE nor COLUMN_ADD can automatically create multiple dynamic columns from a subquery with more than 1 row.